# RTL8723DE wifi driver error in ubuntu 18.04 after updating kernel to 5.3.0-59

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless

a few days ago after an update my wifi stopped working, my controller is rtl8111 / 8168/8411 and I am using ubuntu 18.04, the kernel is 5.3.0-59.

I enclose more information:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:03ac Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I accept any type of advice or suggestion, I am a novice.

Reply:

It did not work, run reboot, and the wifi is still not usable. I will edit the publication, to show you the content of the terminal with the commands you suggested. “no wireless adapter was detected”

Thanks also.

> :~$ sudo apt update ~$ sudo apt install git dkms Leyendo lista de
> paquetes... Hecho Creando árbol de dependencias        Leyendo la
> información de estado... Hecho dkms ya está en su versión más reciente
> (2.3-3ubuntu9.7). git ya está en su versión más reciente
> (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7). 0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para
> eliminar y 7 no actualizados. ~$ git clone -b rtw88
> https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git fatal: la ruta de destino
> 'rtlwifi_new' ya existe y no es un directorio vacío. ~$ sudo dkms add
> ./rtlwifi_new Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtlwifi-new-0.6 You
> cannot add the same module/version combo more than once. ~$ sudo dkms
> install rtlwifi-new/0.6
>
> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
>
> Building module: cleaning build area........(bad exit status: 2) make
> -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.3.0-59-generic -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-59-generic/build
> M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build................Cc.................(bad
> exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new:
> 0.6 not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-59-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: How is  rtl8111 / 8168/8411 related to Wi-Fi? Your adapter is `rtl8723de`.

Answer (score 0):

Driver for `rtl8723de` is installed this way:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

You probably installed an old driver that is incompatible with the new kernel.

Comment: It did not work, run reboot, and the wifi is still not usable. I will edit the publication, to show you the content of the terminal with the commands you suggested. “no wireless adapter was detected”

 Thanks also.